# PA interpreting a theory which proves the consistency of PA

Tags: logic, model-theory, incompleteness

This question probably has a simple answer, but I just don't see it yet so I thought I'd ask it here.

We know that ZFC proves the consistency of PA.  Yet, we use PA as the meta-theory to analyze ZFC, under the even stronger hypothesis that ZFC is consistent.  Doesn't assuming that ZFC is consistent (in the meta-theory PA) imply then that the meta-theory PA is consistent, contradicting Godel's second incompleteness theorem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gödel's second incompleteness theorem only says that a theory (satisfying certain hypotheses) cannot *prove* its own consistency.  There's nothing wrong with working within such a theory and additionally *assuming* it is consistent; you will just never be able to prove that assumption within the theory itself.  So PA can't prove the consistency of PA, but there's nothing wrong with working in PA and additionally assuming the consistency of PA (or something which implies the consistency of PA).

To put it another way, when you assume the consistency of ZFC, that means you are no longer working just in PA: instead, you are working in PA+Con(ZFC).  It is perfectly fine if PA+Con(ZFC) can prove Con(PA); you would only have a problem with Gödel if it could prove Con(PA+Con(ZFC)).

Comment: +1. For the OP, another way to look at things (responding to the last paragraph) is that when we say e.g. "The independence of CH from ZFC is provable in PA," what we mean is "PA proves "$\color{red}{\mbox{If ZFC is consistent}}$, then so are ZFC+CH and ZFC+$\neg$CH." So we *are* working in PA, but there's an unspoken assumption in the theorem we're proving in PA.

Comment: @NoahSchweber To put it another way: it is one thing to assume consistency of a theory T, and another to assume provability of consistency of T in T, and another to assume provability of consistency of T in S.

Comment: That said, I realized another small confusion I had, that has to do with Eric's answer.  We know that PA+$\neg$Con(PA) is consistent.  (Here Con(PA) is the arithmetical encoding of what "should" be the consistency of PA.)  How do model theorists differentiate between assuming, meta-mathematically, that PA is inconsistent vs. assuming $\neg$Con(PA)?